# How can I use Stripe checkout with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

[This library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-stripe-checkout) makes it easy to use Stripe checkout in React projects. But I don't want all of the extra options, and I want to understand how to achieve this functionality myself.

**How can I get a basic Stripe checkout button**, like the one below, **in my React project**? I do not want to use any external libraries. I do not want to use Stripe.js.

Here's the code for the basic Stripe checkout button *as distinct from Stripe.js checkout*:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="KEY"
    data-amount="999"
    data-name="Company Name"
    data-description="Widget"
    data-image="/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
```

[Here's a live example](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/tutorial), in case that code snippet can't be run.

---

### Problem

I can't get the button to display if it is within a React class. I think this has to do with rendering and loading the Stripe script.

Answer (score 2):

A direct translation of your code to make it work in react could be:

```
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" ;
script.className="stripe-button";
script.dataset.key="KEY";
script.dataset.amount="999";
script.dataset.name="Company Name";
script.dataset.description="Widget";
script.dataset.image="img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png";
script.dataset.locale="auto";
script.dataset.zipCode="true"; // Note camelCase!
let form = document.getElementById('THEFORM');
form.appendChild(script);
```

This code can be placed in componentDidMount and THEFORM is the form element that you put in the render function. But take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41500470/7584643) to see how it really should be done.

Comment: But , I tried this one but it didn't work for me .... It just say 'script' element have no properties like dataset and so and so

Answer (score -1):

If you're using `jsx`, `class` is a reserved keyword. Use `className` instead:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" className="stripe-button"
    data-key="KEY"
    data-amount="999"
    data-name="Company Name"
    data-description="Widget"
    data-image="/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
```

Comment: I understand. Everything compiles with no warnings, but no checkout button is ever created.